Wiring broke off under hood — What did it do?
2010 Silverado 1500
This wire was hanging by a thread from the bolt circled in red (under the hood, below the windsheild, driver's side). The wire broke off when I touched it.
What did the other end of the wire connect to? Was it important?



I'm pretty sure this is a ground strap going to the hood. Why it's there, I don't know. Both my 2006 Silverado had one as well as my 2004 Suburban. Is it important? I really couldn't say. It won't keep the truck from running. GM put them on there for a reason, though. It'd be very easy to replace, though. Just get a length of wire, put connectors on either end, put the old wiring loom on it, then relocate it between the cowl and the hood. Oh, then close the hood.
EDIT: I went out to take a picture of the one on my 2018 Silverado and lo-n-behold ... it doesn't have one. I know my older Silvy and 'Burban had the strap. I had used the lug on the body side of 'Burban to ground a pair of aftermarket electric fans I installed.

Is an under-hood light an optional extra? Maybe it's cheaper to always ground the hood even when the lamp isn't installed.

@AndrewMorton - Not on the newer GM trucks. I did have a 91 Suburban which had a retractable underhood light wired up to it. It had enough wire you could pull it down and take the light all the way to the back. Plus, it had a magnet in the base of the light so you could put it somewhere and it would stay. One of the coolest features of that big beast, lol. I think the reason for the ground strap might be to help prevent corrosion. With it grounded, it's less likely.

Related: What is this wire?

This ended up being the right part: Ground Cable - GM (15179982).

If anyone's interested, this is what the innards of the old part look like: https://i.sstatic.net/MsEVlDpB.jpg. The black plastic backing strip is kind of like a really thick and rigid zip tie.

@User1974 - Just a regular ground strap duded up to look purdy, lol.

For our notes: The new ground cable seems to have solved an issue where the radio/clock display lights were dim and flickering.
